# Bash execution is not working with one liner, how to fix that?

Tags: bash

I have a bash file, which I kept remotely and below steps are working.

```
curl -fsSL -o check.sh https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testbash/tmp/check.sh
chmod 700 check.sh
sudo ./check.sh
```

But, if I change that to one line command, it is not working/showing any output.

```
curl https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testbash/tmp/check.sh | bash
```

The actual code is:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
count_apt=`whereis apt`
count_yum=`whereis yum`
## echo ${#count_apt} ${#count_yum}
if (( ${#count_yum} > 4 )); then
 echo "---Redhat distributions are not supported---"
 exit 0
fi

if (( ${#count_apt} > 4 )); then
 echo "---Found Ubuntu Distribution---"
 echo "---Started installation of dependencies---"
 apt install -y curl
 wget https://xenowulf-deb.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
 apt install -y ./agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
 wget https://xenowulf-deb.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
 apt install -y ./xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
 echo "---Completed installation of dependencies---"
 echo "---Started installation of main package with its dependencies: xenowulf-ai---"
 wget https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testdeb2/tmp/xenowulf-ai_1.0_all.deb
 apt install -y ./xenowulf-ai_1.0_all.deb
 echo "---Completed installation of main pacakge: xenowulf-ai---"
fi
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Your first command, the one that works, uses curl's `-L` option which is (from `man curl`):

```
   -L, --location
          (HTTP)  If the server reports that the requested page has moved
          to a different location (indicated with a Location: header  and
          a  3XX  response code), this option will make curl redo the re‐
          quest on the new place. [. . .]
```

The way your URL works seems to be through that kind of redirection since without the `-L` option, you get nothing:

```
$ url="https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testbash/tmp/check.sh"
$ curl "$url"  2>/dev/null | wc
      0       0       0
```

But with it, you get output:

```bash
$ curl -L "$url" 2>/dev/null 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
count_apt=`whereis apt`
count_yum=`whereis yum`
## echo ${#count_apt} ${#count_yum}
if (( ${#count_yum} > 4 )); then
 echo "---Redhat distributions are not supported---"
 exit 0
fi

if (( ${#count_apt} > 4 )); then
 echo "---Found Debian Distribution---"
 echo "---Started installation of dependencies---"
 apt install -y curl
 wget https://xenowulf-deb.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
 apt install -y ./agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
 wget https://xenowulf-deb.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
 apt install -y ./xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
 echo "---Completed installation of dependencies---"
 echo "---Started installation of main package with its dependencies: xenowulf-ai---"
 wget https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testdeb2/tmp/xenowulf-ai_1.0_all.deb
 apt install -y ./xenowulf-ai_1.0_all.deb
 echo "---Completed installation of main pacakge: xenowulf-ai---"
fi
```

So all you need to do is use the `-L` option and then pass it to `sudo bash` (since you need to run it as root):

```
curl -L "$url"  | sudo bash
```

This is very risky, of course, and only run things like this if you are 100% the script is safe. Also, it seems weird that you are checking for the presence of `curl` in the script if you are using `curl` to download it. You already know `curl` is available. In any case, although you are testing for `curl`, your script actually uses `wget` instead. There are various other improvements you can make (backticks are deprecated, use `var=$(command)` instead of `` var=`command` ``; there are better ways of checking the distribution since yum can be installed on non RedHat based distros and `apt` on non-Debian ones), but those are off topic here.